# Make a table without showing the first cell

Tags: html, css

I want my table to be like that :
[wanted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gPS.png)

Mine, is currently like that :
[current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imOA3.png)

The difference is that in the wanted table, the first cell (at position 0;0) is removed.
I also want to border to be updated, in order to make it goes through the bottom and the right of the removed cell.

The current result is that :[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhniF.png)

here is my current code :

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.removeCell {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Titre du document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\desktopStyle.scss">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="removeCell">Mois</th>
        <th>Data</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Janvier</td>
        <td>10.01.2014</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Février</td>
        <td>10.01.2014</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: has table borders too ?

Comment: Please upload more code

Comment: Yes G-Cyrillus.

Comment: I just did it ninadepina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the border on the first td

```css
td{
border: 1px solid black;
width:40px;
height:10px;

}
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}

#one{
border:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id='one'></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```